# dimdesc() error from FactoMineR package in the building of PCA

Tags: r, pca

Using the data available on FactoMineR package: (http://factominer.free.fr/book/orange.csv), I created a PCA and after a PCA with supplementary information. The latter step when I used the function dimdesc() I obtained an error that surfing through internet I was not able to find a way to solve it.
I post here if someone could help me. I attach below my code. Thanks on advance for your comments/hints.

```
data_orange<-read.delim("orange.csv", header = T, sep = ";")
data_orange_subset <- data_orange[,1:8]
res.pca<-PCA(data_orange_subset, graph = F) 
dimdesc(res.pca,axes=1:2)
```

--> This works

When considering supplementary information in the PCA:

```
data_orange_2 <- data_orange[,-c(16,17)]
 
res.pca.all <- PCA(data_orange_2, graph = F,
                    quanti.sup = 9:15,
                    quali.sup =  1) 
dimdesc(res.pca.all, axes = 1:2)
```

> Error in if (sum(tabF[, 2] <= proba) > 0) resF <- tabF[tabF[, 2] <= proba, :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I've checked for NA values in dataframe but it is not the case.

```
SessionInfo()

R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 19.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] factoextra_1.0.7.999 ggplot2_3.3.6        FactoMineR_2.4      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] ggrepel_0.9.1        Rcpp_1.0.8.3         lattice_0.20-45      tidyr_1.2.0         
 [5] assertthat_0.2.1     digest_0.6.29        utf8_1.2.2           R6_2.5.1            
 [9] backports_1.4.1      evaluate_0.15        pillar_1.7.0         rlang_1.0.3         
[13] rstudioapi_0.13      minqa_1.2.4          car_3.1-0            nloptr_2.0.3        
[17] Matrix_1.4-1         DT_0.23              rmarkdown_2.13       labeling_0.4.2      
[21] splines_4.1.2        lme4_1.1-29          htmlwidgets_1.5.4    munsell_0.5.0       
[25] broom_0.8.0          compiler_4.1.2       xfun_0.31            pkgconfig_2.0.3     
[29] faraway_1.0.7        htmltools_0.5.2      flashClust_1.01-2    tidyselect_1.1.2    
[33] tibble_3.1.7         gridExtra_2.3        dendextend_1.15.2    viridisLite_0.4.0   
[37] fansi_1.0.3          crayon_1.5.1         dplyr_1.0.9          withr_2.5.0         
[41] ggpubr_0.4.0         MASS_7.3-56          leaps_3.1            grid_4.1.2          
[45] nlme_3.1-157         gtable_0.3.0         lifecycle_1.0.1      DBI_1.1.2           
[49] magrittr_2.0.3       scales_1.2.0         cli_3.3.0            carData_3.0-5       
[53] farver_2.1.0         ggsignif_0.6.3       viridis_0.6.2        scatterplot3d_0.3-41
[57] ellipsis_0.3.2       generics_0.1.2       vctrs_0.4.1          boot_1.3-28         
[61] ggsci_2.9            tools_4.1.2          glue_1.6.2           purrr_0.3.4         
[65] abind_1.4-5          fastmap_1.1.0        yaml_2.3.5           colorspace_2.0-3    
[69] cluster_2.1.3        rstatix_0.7.0        knitr_1.39
```